# Regular expression in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

Hi I have many xml file, in each I would like change this:

```
<DNI code="000.010.000.100">
  <Item>1580634903404</Item>
</DNI>
```

for:

```
<DNI code="000.010.000.100">
  <Item>0000000000</Item>
</DNI>
```

for example.

Please need your help.

Sorry,

this:

```
<DNI code="000.010.000.100">
  <Item>15.80634.903.4-P</Item>
</DNI>
<XDR code="000.010.000.020">
   <Item>9384934P</Item>
 </XDR>
  <YXR code="000.060.010.0030">
   <Item>Hello</Item>
 </YXR>
```

result:

```
<DNI code="000.010.000.100">
  <Item>0000000000</Item>
</DNI>
```

Thanks.

Comment: learn a bit about regular expressions and the use a expression tester  (e.g [Fileformat.Info](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for: `<Item>\d+[\<\w\"=\./\>\-\s]+</YXR>`

Replace with: `<Item>0000000000</Item>
</DNI>`